# Cambiar texto de Boton de acción de una notificacion Android, Java y añadir una función a ese boton

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

Tengo lo siguiente para crear una notificación en Android, mi duda es si en el .addAction, en lugar de iniciar un servicio, puedo ejecutar una función y renombrar el botón.
Por ejemplo al dar click en "Activar", ejecute una función llamada miFuncion() y cambie de texto a "Desactivar" y viceversa.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity2.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Intent servicioIntent = new Intent(this,MiServicio.class);
        PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,servicioIntent,0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "ID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("Titulo")
                .setContentText("Contenido")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Activar",actionIntent)//Aquí en lugar de pasar un servicio pasar miFuncion()
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

       NotificationCompat.Builder builder = notificacion();
       NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
       notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}





 private void  miFuncion(option){
    //Ejecutar cada vez que doy click en boton creado en notificación 
     if(option=="activar"){
     //Codigo a ejecutar
    }
    if(option=="desactivar"){
     //Codigo a ejecutar
    }

            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ejecutar `miFuncion()` cuando se presione el botón puedes utilizar un `BroadcastReceiver`.
En el `Manifest` declaras el `receiver`:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVAR" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Luego en el método `onCreate()` en lugar de pasar el Servicio pasas el `BroadcastReceiver`

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTIVAR");
PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
builder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Activar", actionIntent);
```

Entonces en la clase `Receiver` en el método `onReceiver()` para cambiar el texto del botón de `ACTIVAR` a `DESACTIVAR` y viceversa puedes volver a lanzar la notificación

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        miFucion();
        String action = "DESACTIVAR";
        PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            ...
            ...
            builder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, action, pendingIntent)
            ...
            ...
    }

    private void miFucion(){
        
    }
}
```

Para alternar el texto del botón de `ACTIVAR` a `DESACTIVAR` busqué un forma, como utlizar `putExtra()` en `onCreate()` y `getStringExtra()` en el receiver pero no funcionó. La única forma que se me ocurre es utilizar `SharedPreferences`, pero si se te ocurre una mejor solución compártela con nosotros